# How to Hide and Unhide Tabs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a monthly report that shows the previous month's information. (Eventually, I will extract updated information into the report.)

I am looking to automatically hide the previous month's tabs and open the current month's tabs.

For example: For September 2018. The visible tabs show "Aug18." I am looking to automatically have the "Aug18" tabs hidden and the "Sep18" tabs unhidden.

Comment: worksheets("Name of the Sheet").visible = xlHidden

Answer (score 1):

1) Get the current date into the format we can use for testing "Greater than" type logic YYYYMM:

```
Dim currentDate As String
currentDate=Format(Now(), "YYYYMM")
```

2) Loop through your worksheets:

```
Dim currentDate As String
currentDate=Format(Now(), "YYYYMM")

Dim ws as Worksheet
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

Next ws
```

3) Inside that loop convert test if it's a worksheet named like a month. Using `InStr` here:

```
Dim currentDate As String
currentDate = Format(Now(), "YYYYMM")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim thisTabDate As String
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'Test to see if this is in the right format
    If InStr(1, "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec", Left(ws.Name, 3)) Then            
    End If
 Next ws
```

4) If it is, then format the tab's name to be the same YYYYMM and set it's visibility

```
Dim currentDate As String
currentDate = Format(Now(), "YYYYMM")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim thisTabDate As String
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'Test to see if this is in the right format
    If InStr(1, "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec", Left(ws.Name, 3)) Then
        'This is messy, but we are just cutting the tab name up, turning it into an actual date, and then formatting that.
        thisTabDate = Format(CDate(Left(ws.Name, 3) & "-01-" & Right(ws.Name, 2)), "YYYYMM")

        'Set the visible True/False to the result of the test
        ws.Visible = (thisTabDate >= currentDate)
    End If
 Next ws
```

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 thanks. Code still works, but looks uglier. Fixed.

Comment: Not to complicate - but wouldn't you also have to make sure at least 1 worksheet is always visible?

Comment: @BigBen This method should work assuming a September sheet exists, don't you think? It'd just error when it got to the end anyway

Comment: Maybe you could try to select a sheet based on `Left(MonthName(Month(Now))),3)` and hide everything else?

Comment: I don't think you'll get an error here, but yes the potential exists that this could hide every sheet if you don't have at least one sheet that doesn't follow the naming convention `MMMYY` (or one sheet with the current MMMYY value). Unless... excel doesn't let you hide every sheet. I guess I've never tried that. :)

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 that would probably be a lot cleaner. I went with the conversion to YYYYMM thinking "any sheet less than current date", but then just ended up using an `=` compare... I may change that to be `>=` so all this extra work is worth it.

Comment: I think I've tried hiding them all and it just yelled at me instead. Yeah there's just a ton of ways to tackle this one